# Prolog minimum value in a list

Tags: prolog, logic-programming

I'm working on defining a predicate `min_in_list/2` that would find the smallest value on a list. If there is less than 2 elements in the list the program should output `"Error: There are not enough elements in the list"` and if an element on the list is not a digit Eg. [2,a,3]. The program should output `"Error: The element is not a number"`. I created a predicate that would find the smallest value and checking if the list has less than two values but I'm having problem on checking if an element of a list is not a digit and outputting the error message

My code:

```
    min_in_list([Min],_):- write('ERROR: List has fewer than two elements.').
min_in_list([],_):- write('ERROR: List has fewer than two elements.').
min_in_list([Min,_],Min).

min_in_list([H,K|T],M) :- 
    H =< K,                           
    min_in_list([H|T],M).

min_in_list([H,K|T],M) :- 
    H > K,                            
    min_in_list([K|T],M).
```

Comment: *It there is less than 2 elements*, shouldn't this be *less than one*? A list with one element still has a minimum...

Comment: No, the predicate that I want should output the error message when is only one element or none.

Comment: You should browse the pre-defined predicate library for Prolog. There are predicates that can help you identify a number versus an atom, for example.

Comment: You probably don't really mean `min_in_list([Min,_],Min).` That would mean that `min_in_list([3,5], 3).` would be true.

Answer (score 1):

The test you're looking for is `number/1`, which tells you whether a value is a number or not. My final code looks like this:

```
min_in_list([], _)  :- domain_error(not_empty_list, []).
min_in_list([X], _) :- domain_error(not_single_item_list, [X]).
min_in_list([X,Y|Rest], Min) :- min_in_list(X, [Y|Rest], Min).

min_in_list(Min, [], Min) :- !.
min_in_list(Min, [X|Rest], FinalMin) :-
    (   number(X) ->
        (NewMin is min(Min, X),
         min_in_list(NewMin, Rest, FinalMin))
    ;
        type_error(number, X)
    ).
```

I'm still not entirely sure how to format a condition like this, but splitting it into separate predicates seems like an awful waste. Hopefully someone will come along and tell me how to format this so that it is attractive.

If you are using SWI-Prolog, you can simplify things using `must_be/2`:

```
min_in_list(Min, [], Min).
min_in_list(Min, [X|Rest], FinalMin) :-
    must_be(number, X),
    NewMin is min(Min, X),
    min_in_list(NewMin, Rest, FinalMin).
```

Comment: `must_be/2` is better, because it throws an `instantiation_error` for an uninstantiated `X`. OTOH, `(is)/2` does similar checking itself already. The only difference is that `X = 1+1` is accepted by `(is)/2`, but not by `must_be/2`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution can be:

```
list(Min, [Min]).
list(Min, [H|T]) :- list(PMin, T), Min is min(H, PMin).
```

However it must be note, that it will be stack overhead on big arrays.